# Why does the following code extract characters instead of blanks?

Tags: java

I saw a code segment as follows:

```
public class Practice
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String i = new String("I love you");
        System.out.println(doSomething(i));
    }
    public static String doSomething( String s )
    {
        final String BLANK = " ";
        String str = "";
        String temp;
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            temp = s.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (!(temp.equals(BLANK)))
            {
                str += temp;
            }

        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

I am very confused by the code here. I believe that whenever the for loop runs, one of the characters of the String will be extracted out. For example, when i = 0, temp should be "I", and i = 1, " ", i = 2, "l", etc. And when temp = " ", the if statement states that the blank will be adding to the String str. So whenever for-loop is run, the temp will change accordingly and hence cannot store the value unless its value is " ".

The output is Iloveyou.

Comment: *And when temp = " "* - **No**. When `temp` **is not** equal to `" "`. That's what the `!` means.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
   if (!(temp.equals(BLANK)))
        {
            str += temp;
        }
```

**IF** temp **IS NOT** (the ! means NOT) **BLANK**,

then do: `str += temp;`